# simple C crossword how to avoid duplicate words

Tags: c, string, crossword

I am new here and also new with coding.
How can i find a 'bug' in a simple crossword program, written in C, that could, generate (unwanted) duplicate words?

All tips and suggestions are appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

char puzzle[ROWS][COLUMNS];

char allWords[20][10] = {
    "GIRL", "BOY", "SHIP", "CAT", "FOG",
    "KITE", "BAG", "STAMP", "ZOOM", "JOY",
    "CAR", "BUS", "VAN", "BOAT", "BIKE",
    "TURBO", "SCHOOL", "COVID", "VIRUS", "STAR"
};

char fourWords[4][10];

char getRandomCharacter()
{
    int r = (rand() % 26) + 65;
    return (char)r;
}   

void getFourRandomWords() // This code can generate duplicate words -- try to fix it
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        strcpy(fourWords[i], allWords[rand() % 20]);
    }
}

void createBlankPuzzle()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            puzzle[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}

void displayPuzzel()
{
    int i, j, rowNum = 0;
    char x = 'A';
   
    // First display column names
    printf("  ");
    for (i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
        printf("%c ", x + i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf("%d ", rowNum);
        rowNum++;
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            printf("%c ", puzzle[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void putHorizzontalWord(char word[10])
{
    int rRow, rCol, ok, i;

    do {
        rRow = rand() % 10;
        rCol = rand() % 10;

        ok = 1;
        if (rCol + strlen(word) < 10) {
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
                if (puzzle[rRow][rCol + i] == '*' ||
                    puzzle[rRow][rCol + i] == word[i])
                {
                    puzzle[rRow][rCol + i] = word[i];
                } else {
                    ok = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ok = 0;
        }
    } while (ok == 0);
}

void fillPuzzleWithWords()
{
    int i, orientation;
    getFourRandomWords();

    for (i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
        orientation = 0; //rand() % 3; // To generate a random number from 0, 1, & 2
        if (orientation == 0) {
            putHorizzontalWord(fourWords[i]);
        } else
        if(orientation == 1)
        {
            // put word vertical
        } else {
            // put word diagonal
        }
    }
} 

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    createBlankPuzzle();
    fillPuzzleWithWords();
    displayPuzzel();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I executed the code about 10 times and it did reproduced the same word three times. The thing is that I do not understand how the word are picked/chosen from that list hence I do not know how to interact with these lines.

Comment: There is no ```if``` loop in ```c```, or any other language that I know of.  I didn't read the code but according to the description, a simple for loop and comparison would suffice before adding the new word to the array.

Comment: ok, i meant if else; my bad!
Anyhow, where do i add the for loop? I can't even see where the new word function is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to produce distinct words, you can simply iterate over the words selected so far to check if the newly drawn word is different from all the previous ones:

```
void getFourRandomWords(void) {
    // draw 4 words from the list, no duplicates
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4;) {
        const char *w = allWords[rand() % 20];
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (strcmp(fourWords[i], w) == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (j == i) {
            // add the word if it compared different from all previous ones
            strcpy(fourWords[i], w);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The above naive method may be very inefficient if choosing n from n, as a matter of fact it is not even guaranteed to finish.

Here is a different approach to cap the number of iterations:

```
void getFourRandomWords(void) {
    int draws[4];
    // draw 4 words from the list, no duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int n = rand() % (20 - i);
        int j;
        for (j = 4 - i; j < 4 && n >= draws[j]; j++) {
            draws[j - 1] = draws[j];
            n++;
        }
        draws[j - 1] = n;
        strcpy(fourWords[i], allWords[n]);
    }
}
```

Here is yet another approach with a single loop and linear time and space complexity:

```
void getFourRandomWords(void) {
    // list of possible word numbers
    int draws[20] = {  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
                      10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
    // draw 4 words from the list, no duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // draw a number from i to 19
        int n = i + rand() % (20 - i);
        // select the word from the list
        strcpy(fourWords[i], allWords[draws[n]]);
        // swap the word number and the i-th slot
        // this way the selected number is removed from the list
        draws[n] = draws[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the 2nd/middle approach, although in one instance of execution it did repeat the same word twice on the same puzzle (or maybe I run the unsaved code, i am not sure). I will keep trying but so far it seems the best solution.

Comment: @however: sorry about this, but there was a mistake in the second algorithm: the array `draws` must be sorted for proper operation. I amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: The third one is most interesting because you could easily make it a uniform distribution by, instead of 20, shrinking the array; in this case, I think it can be seen as an in-place version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your reply. To be honest, you may as well speak Japanese as I don't understand, or know, what that is.
I also realize that, perhhpas, I am asking too much so, tmrw I will work on it and, try at least to do no.4

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for the time spent on it and PLEASE, do not apologize for helping.
I have now the flow correct but I can't fill the grid with random letter once the non-duplicated words have been placed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

//Creating two arrays Columns and Rows
char puzzle[ROWS][COLUMNS];

//List of words from which four will be picked up by the program, with which the user to play will search
char allWords[20][10] = {"GIRL" , "BOY" , "SHIP" , "CAT" , "FOG" , "KITE" , "BAG" , "STAMP" , "ZOOM" , "JOY", "CAR" , "BUS" , "VAN" , "BOAT" , "BIKE" , "TURBO" , "SCHOOL" , "DOVIC" , "VIRUS" , "STAR"};

char fourWords[4][10];

//creates random characters from ASCII starting at 65 (=A)
char getRandomCharacter()
{
    int r = (rand() % 26) + 65;
    return (char)r;
}

//pick 4 random words from a list of 20
void getFourRandomWords() {
    int draws[4];
    // draw 4 words from the list, no duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int n = rand() % (20 - i);
        int j;
        for (j = 4 - i; j < 4 && n >= draws[j]; j++) {
            draws[j - 1] = draws[j];
            n++;
        }
        draws[j - 1] = n;
        strcpy(fourWords[i], allWords[n]);
    }
}

// word to be displayed/searched by the user (I CAN'T GET THIS PART WO WORK)
void displayWords(){
    int words = (rand() % 4);
    printf("%s\n " ,&words);
}

//Create a grid filled only with asterisks
void createBlankPuzzle()
{
    int i , j;

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            puzzle [i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}
/*
//Create a grid filled with random characters
void createNewPuzzle()
{
    int i , j;

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            puzzle [i][j] = getRandomCharacter();
        }
    }
}
*/
//Display the character-populated grid
void displayPuzzle()
{
    int i , j , rowNum = 0;
    char x = 'A';

    // First display column names
    printf("  ");
    for(i=0; i<COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ",x + i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0;i < ROWS;i++)
    {
        printf("%d " ,rowNum);
        rowNum++;
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ",puzzle[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//Check horizontal orientation and place the word if available spaces allow it
void putHorizzontalWord(char word[10])
{
    int rRow, rCol , ok , i;

    do
    {
        rRow = rand() % 10;
        rCol = rand() % 10;

        ok = 1;
        if(rCol + strlen(word) < 10)
        {
            for(i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++)
            {
                if(puzzle[rRow][rCol + i] == '*' ||
                    puzzle[rRow][rCol + i] == word[i])
                {
                    puzzle[rRow][rCol + i] = word[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ok = 0;
        }
    }
    while(ok == 0);
}

//Check vertical orientation and place the word if available spaces allow it
void putVerticalWord(char word[10]) //this, doesn't seem to work'
{
    int rRow, rCol , ok , i;

    do
    {
        rRow = rand() % 10;
        rCol = rand() % 10;

        ok = 1;
        if(rRow + strlen(word) < 10)
        {
            for(i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++)
            {
                if(puzzle[rRow + i][rCol] == '*' ||
                    puzzle[rRow + i][rCol] == word[i])
                {
                    puzzle[rRow + i][rCol] = word[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ok = 0;
        }
    }
    while(ok == 0);
}

//Check diagonal orientation and place the word if available spaces allow it
void putDiagonalWord(char word[10]) //this, doesn't seem to work'
{
    int rRow, rCol , ok , i;

    do
    {
        rRow = rand() % 10;
        rCol = rand() % 10;

        ok = 2;
        if(rRow + strlen(word) < 10)
        {
            for(i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++)
            {
                if(puzzle[rRow + i][rCol + i] == '*' ||
                    puzzle[rRow + i][rCol + i] == word[i])
                {
                    puzzle[rRow + i][rCol + i] = word[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ok = 0;
        }
    }
    while(ok == 0);
}

void fillPuzzleWithWords()
{
    int i , orientation;
    getFourRandomWords();


    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        orientation = 0; //rand() % 3; // To generate a random number from 0, 1, & 2
        if(orientation == 0)
        {
            putHorizzontalWord(fourWords[i]);
        }
        else if(orientation == 1)
        {
            putVerticalWord(fourWords[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            putDiagonalWord(fourWords[i]);
        }
    }
}

//Create a user-interactive menu
void mainMenu()
{
    char menuChoice;
    do
    {
        printf("\n~~~ DAILY CROSSWORD ~~~\n");
        printf("1. New game\n");
        printf("2. Exit\n");
        menuChoice = getchar();

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
            case '1': displayPuzzle();
                printf("\n------------------------");
                printf("\nUse coordinate to solve\nthe puzzle; i.e. C3, G3\n");
                printf("------------------------\n");
                printf("\n"); break;
        }

    } while (menuChoice != '2');
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    createBlankPuzzle();
    displayPuzzle();
    fillPuzzleWithWords();


    mainMenu();
    getchar();
    printf("Thank you for playing today! :)\nGood Bye");
    return 0;
}
```

Would anyone guide me to the right direction?
Highly appreciated

Comment: After countless (trial&error) moving code lines around, I managed to have option 'zero' (I mean the starting blank puzzle filled with asterisks, as there is no such option), '2' and '4' to work.
I still cannot get the most important option, option '1', to work (columns and rows filled with random letters and 4 words hidden in between).
I guess option '3' is not that important, as I could just add the HowTo hint on any screen.
Any suggestions?  Please

Comment: by the way, I modified  option '2', in the sense that, the user will not have this option while playing but only as an initial option to visualize the words, while the crossword is still filled with asterisks (although, not a requirement, I would love, to have it to show the words, in bold, when the columns&rows are populated with random characters too)

Comment: Perhaps, a little too late, i realized to have worded my initial questions wrong. I just learned about such forum's policies about not doing/helping members to do their assignments and I respect that although, i believe that, at some point in time, we were all learners and whether if was a book, a tutor or a stranger showing you how to get the job done  it was still formative and instructional.
I apologize for my "disrespectful" request and I would like to add that I didn't expect anyone to do the work for me.

Comment: I am actually trying very hard to solve it myself, understanding as much as i can of a subject that I don't care much about  and that I am only "forced" to attend & pass because it is part of an curriculum degree which has little, if anything, to do with programming.

Comment: Please modify the existing question or post a new question instead of continuing a conversation and/or your thought process with an Answer post